# Disable every non checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, input

I have a bunch of forms with a checkbox in each of them and when a condition is met i want to disable every checkbox that is NOT checked.

I've tried doing this but with no luck

```
if (updateShowcasedProducts.length == 12) {                                    
 document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').disabled = true;
    }
```

I would preferably only use vanilla javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
if (updateShowcasedProducts.length == 12) {
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(i => i.disabled = true);
}
```

Edit: I was too slow. Already suggested by @Gunther: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65692054/4261813

Answer (score 6):

querySelectorAll returns a NodeList object, you have to use that object to iterate through the elements and disable them.

```
if (updateShowcasedProducts.length == 12) {                                    
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').forEach((element) => {
       element.disabled = true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to loop through the results of `querySelectorAll`.

```
if (updateShowcasedProducts.length == 12) {                                    
    els = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)');
    for (const el of els) {
      el.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first use a class for all those inputs what are checkboxes. And then use checked property:

```
let checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
checkBoxes.forEach(checkBox)=>{
    if(!checkBox.checked){
          checkBox.disabled=true;
    };
});
```

Comment: Doesn't appear OP actually uses a class called `checkbox`

Comment: In the case he uses that class it would be an easy solution i think.

Comment: Would require more existing code changes, but I understand your logic.

Comment: Yes you are right, it would be a big change  in the code mmm...i didnt think about it.

Comment: Your solution is more elegant (and flexible) so I will upvote. By "flexible" I mean suppose in the future only certain checkboxes should be included in the disabling and not all that are unchecked.

Comment: I really appreciate it.